# Selenium webdriver can't find my button

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

This is my button link:

```
<a class="button" href="#" onclick="ajaxtoelement('include/system.php?mode=begin&amp;location='+getSelectedValue('location')+'&amp;terminallane='+getSelectedValue('terminallane')+'','keyboard')</a>"
```

And I have tried doing

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='ajaxtoelement('include/system.php?mode=begin&amp;location='+getSelectedValue('location')+'&amp;terminallane='+getSelectedValue('terminallane')]"));
```

Why can't selenium still find the button I'm specifying?

Comment: `ajaxtoelement('include/system....` is not the class of the element

Comment: can you share the error log of your IDE console ?

Comment: Besides what Fran said, you've tried to nest single quotes within single quotes; XPath can't parse that.

Answer (score 2):

It should be accessed via `onclick` and not `class` one simple way is,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@onclick, 'onClickValue')]");
```

Comment: Looks like you have missed to close ']'

Comment: @Vicky yes. fixed!! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your HTML structure, but

**How many buttons do you have?**

If you only have one button you don't need xpath, use the simpler way:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("button"));
```

If there are several more buttons, but the button you described is the only one that contains for example the word "terminallane":

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class = 'button' and contains(@onclick, 'terminallane')]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below xpath::

```
//a[@href='#']
```

else

```
//a[contains(@onclick, 'ajaxtoelement('include/system.php?mode=begin&amp;location='+getSelectedValue('location')+'&amp;terminallane='+getSelectedValue('terminallane')+'','keyboard')')]
```